# Adjust font size local table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

My minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\section{My First Section}
\section{My Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{My First Appendix}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}

\section{My Second Appendix}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Now I like to adjust the font size of the "Contents" header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve it is to employ `\etocsettocstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{etoc}
\makeatletter
    \etocsettocstyle
    {\section *{\Huge\contentsname%
% FOLLOWING TWO LINES OPTIONAL DEPENDING ON YOUR NEED
%                \@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \contentsname}
%                         {\MakeUppercase \contentsname}%
    }}
    {}%
\def\etocstandarddisplaystyle{\etocarticlestyle}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{My First Section}
\section{My Second Section}

\begin{appendices}
\section{My First Appendix}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}

\section{My Second Appendix}
\localtableofcontents
\subsection{My First Subsection}
\subsection{My Second Subsection}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]